# simplemodal autoclose after delay

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'd like to do this:

```
$.modal("<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>").delay(500).close();
```

I also like to close the modal div when clicking anywhere on the screen, so it is not really modal ;-)

But daisychaining appears to be not working. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$.modal('<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>', {
    overlayClose: true,
    onShow: function() {
        setTimeout($.modal.close, 500);
    }
})
```

#### Update

```
$.modal('<div>HELLO</div>', {
    overlayClose: true,
    onShow: function() {
        var timer;
        $('#simplemodal-container').bind({
            mouseenter: function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                timer = setTimeout($.modal.close, 1500);
            }
        })
        .trigger('mouseleave');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It came to mind that it could be handy to let the modal stay open when the mouse is over the modal. That requires clearing and resetting the time out I think. Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but did you try something like this?

```
var $modal = $.modal("<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>").delay(500).close();
$('body').not($modal).click(function() {
    $modal.close();
});
```